# Drawing a Long String on to a Bitmap results in Drawing Issues

Tags: c#, .net, text, bitmap, gdi+

I'm working with drawing a long string to a bitmap (talking more than a million characters), including multiline characters `\r\n`, written by a `StringBuilder`.

My Text to Bitmap code is as follows:

```
public static Bitmap GetBitmap(string input, Font inputFont,
    Color bmpForeground, Color bmpBackground) {
    Image bmpText = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    try {
        // Create a graphics object from the image.
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpText);

        // Measure the size of the text when applied to image.
        SizeF inputSize = g.MeasureString(input, inputFont);
        // Create a new bitmap with the size of the text.
        bmpText = new Bitmap((int)inputSize.Width,
            (int)inputSize.Height);

        // Instantiate graphics object, again, since our bitmap
        // was modified.
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpText);

        // Draw a background to the image.
        g.FillRectangle(new Pen(bmpBackground).Brush,
            new Rectangle(0, 0,
            Convert.ToInt32(inputSize.Width),
            Convert.ToInt32(inputSize.Height)));

        // Draw the text to the image.
        g.DrawString(input, inputFont,
            new Pen(bmpForeground).Brush, new PointF(0, 0));
    } catch {
        // Draw a blank image with background.
        Graphics.FromImage(bmpText).FillRectangle(
            new Pen(bmpBackground).Brush,
            new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
    }
    return (Bitmap)bmpText;
}
```

Normally, it works as expected -- but only when used for single characters. However, the issue lies when a multitude of characters are used. Simply put, extra lines appear both vertically and horizontally when drawn on to the image.

This effect is demonstrated here, zoomed in 1:1 (see the [full Image](https://i.imgur.com/ITGA9WN.png)):

[image: Top left corner of image]

However, I can render this same text in Notepad++ with just the output of the string and it's essentially as expected:

[image: Top left corner of text]

I can view it in any other text viewer; the result will be the same.

So how, and why, is the program rendering the Bitmap with those 'extra' lines?

Comment: Do you use a fixed font like consolas? You might also try to play with Graphics.TextRenderinghint etc..

Comment: I use Lucida Console, which works a bit better than Consolas for this, if I'm being truthful. I will have a look into the `Graphics` bit, thanks!

Comment: @TaW modifying that property didn't help. In some cases, it increased the prominence of the lines... odd.

Comment: inputs that repro the issue would help anybody looking to try it locally...

Comment: Hm I could reproduce by choosing a font size < 5f. And: the TextRendingHint does influence the spacing of the gaps. I couldn't find one the has no gaps in either direction, though. So you would have to use a larger font..

Comment: Looks like a rounding/moiree effect that shows up with really small font sizes.

Comment: @TaW  Using TextRenderer.MeasureText/TextRenderer.DrawText instead of Graphics.DrawString, I don't see that kind of artifacts. Using Consolas 4em, TextFormatFlags are just set to (Top | Left | NoPadding). The Bitmap is created with `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap([Width], [Height], PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);`

Comment: True! I think you should write it as an answer..

Comment: Sure do look into it. [this is an interesting write-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283631/graphics-drawstring-vs-textrenderer-drawtextwhich-can-deliver-better-quality)

Comment: [Consolas, 4, using @Jimi's comment](https://i.imgur.com/ydHICdj.png)

Comment: Great pattern you have there! -- I think I have enough documentation to explain why the results are so different. I'll post it as soon as I have a moment to write it down.

Comment: Awesome. @Jimi however the problem is with that rendering is that the characters are unrecognisable at size 4. -- I changed to Lucida Console, fontsizes 8 and 12.

Comment: Btw, I had wondered about the colors in the 2nd image. until I noticed colors in some of my own tests. they are artifacts resulting from cleartype/antialiasing and go away with some TextRenderingHints..

Comment: Yeah, they appear there occasionally. The second image in the original post was actually from Notepad++ at minimum font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When drawing a string of characters (ASCII or a form of Unicode encoded symbols) using [Graphics.DrawString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring) with a fixed sized Font, the resulting graphics appear to generate a sort of grid, degrading the visual quality of the rendering.

A solution is to substitute the GDI+ Graphics methods with the GDI methods, using [TextRenderer.MeasureText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext) and [TextRenderer.DrawText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext).

Sample code to correct the problem and to reproduce it.

Load a text file using the default local CodePage encoding. The source text has been saved without any Unicode encoding. If a different encoding is used, the `Encoding.Default` must be substituted with the actual Encoding (e.g. `Encoding.Unicode`, `Encoding.UTF8`...).

The fixed size Font used for all tests is `Lucida Console, 4em Regular`.
Other candidates, usually available, are `Consolas` and `Courier New`.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Read the input text - assume UTF8 Encoding
string text = File.ReadAllText([Source text Path], Encoding.UTF8);

Font font = new Font("Lucida Console", 4, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);

// Use TextRenderer
using (var bitmap = ASCIIArtBitmap(text, font))
    bitmap.Save(@"[FilePath1]", ImageFormat.Png);

// Use GDI+ Graphics
using (var bitmap = ASCIIArtBitmapGdiPlus(text, font))
    bitmap.Save(@"[FilePath2]", ImageFormat.Png);

// Use GraphicsPath
using (var bitmap = ASCIIArtBitmapGdiPlusPath(text, font))
    bitmap.Save(@"[FilePath3]", ImageFormat.Png);

font.Dispose();
```

**`TextRenderer` is first used to eliminate the visual defect reported.**

As a note, both `TextRederer.MeasureText()` and `Graphics.DrawString()`, per the MSDN documentation, should be used to measure a single line of text.
Anyway, it's also known that the text is correctly measured when the text is composed of multiple lines, if a line feed separates those lines.
It can be easily tested, splitting the source text with `Environment.Newline` as separator and multiplying the number of lines by the height of a single line. The result is always the same.

```
private Bitmap ASCIIArtBitmap(string text, Font font)
{
    var flags = TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left | 
                TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.NoClipping;

    Size bitmapSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font, Size.Empty, flags);

    var bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapSize.Width, bitmapSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
        bitmapSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g, text, font, new Size(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), flags);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, text, font, Point.Empty, Color.Black, Color.White, flags);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

*Low resolution rendering, (150 x 55 chars). No grid effect visible*.

[image]

**Using `Graphics.DrawString()`, to reproduce the reported behavior.**

[TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.textrenderinghint) is specified, as an effort to reduce the visual defect. [CompositingQuality.HighSpeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.compositingquality) seems out of place, but it actually, in this case, renders better than `HighQuality`.
[TextContrast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.textcontrast) = 1 makes the resulting image a little darker. With the default setting is too bright and loses details (my opinion, though).

```
private Bitmap ASCIIArtBitmapGdiPlus(string text, Font font)
{
    using (var modelbitmap = new Bitmap(10, 10, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
    using (var modelgraphics = Graphics.FromImage(modelbitmap))
    {
        modelgraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        SizeF bitmapSize = modelgraphics.MeasureString(text, font, Point.Empty, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        var bitmap = new Bitmap((int)bitmapSize.Width, (int)bitmapSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
            g.TextContrast = 1;
            g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

*Medium-low resolution (300 x 110 chars)*, the grid-effect is visible.

[image]

```
           Graphics.DrawString()                    TextRenderer.DrawText()
```

**Another approach, using [GraphicsPath.AddString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addstring)**

The resulting bitmap is a somewhat better, but the grid effect is there anyway.
What can be really noticed, is the difference in speed. [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath) is **way slower** than all other methods tested.

```
private Bitmap ASCIIArtBitmapGdiPlusPath(string text, Font font)
{
    using (var path = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Alternate)) {
        path.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, 4, Point.Empty, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

        var gpRect = Rectangle.Round(path.GetBounds());

        var bitmap = new Bitmap(gpRect.Width, gpRect.Height);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
            g.Clear(Color.White);
            g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;  // Not used
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;   // <= for the Bitmap
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;  // <= for the GraphicsPath
            g.FillPath(Brushes.Black, path);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

**Why the rendering quality is, in this case, so different?**

All depends on the nature of the GDI+ resolution-independent grid-fitted rendering.

From an obscure document, of Microsoft's origin, found on the WayBack Machine:

[GDI+ Text, Resolution Independence, and Rendering Methods.](http://web.archive.org/web/20100116044507/http://windowsclient.net/articles/gdiptext.aspx)

> Grid Fitting, also known as hinting, is the process of adjusting the
> position of pixels in a rendered glyph to make the glyph easily
> legible at smaller sizes. Techniques include aligning glyph stems on
> whole pixels and ensuring similar features of a glyph are affected
> equally.

In an effort to compensates for Grid Fitting, trying to achieve the best appearance possible for a text, the typographic tracking (usually called [letter-spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter-spacing)), is modified.

> When GDI+ displays a line of grid fitted glyphs that are shorter than
> their design width, it follows these general rules:
>
> 1. The line is allowed to contract by up to an `em` without any change of glyph spacing.
> 2. Remaining contraction is made up by increasing the width of any spaces between words, to a maximum of doubling.
> 3. Remaining contraction is made up by introducing blanks pixels between glyphs.

This "effort" seems to be pushed to the point of modifying the [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) pairs of the glyphs.

In a proportional Font, the visual rendering has a benefit, but with a fixed size Font, the previously mentioned calculation produces a sort of grid-alignment, clearly visible when the same symbol is repeated multiple times.

TextRenderer GDI methods, based on clear-type rendering - aimed to the **visual rendering of text on screen** - uses a sub-pixel representation of glyphs. The calculation of letter-spacing is completely different.

[Microsoft ClearType overview.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/cleartype/)

> ClearType works by accessing the individual vertical color stripe
> elements in every pixel of an LCD screen. Before ClearType, the
> smallest level of detail that a computer could display was a single
> pixel, but with ClearType running on an LCD monitor, we can now
> display features of text as small as a fraction of a pixel in width.
> The extra resolution increases the sharpness of the tiny details in
> text display, making it much easier to read over long durations.

The drawback is that this method of calculating the letter-spacing, makes it  unsuited for printing from WinForms. MSDN documentation repeatedly states this.

Other interesting resources on the subject:

[The Art of dev - Text rendering methods comparison or GDI vs. GDI+](https://theartofdev.com/2014/04/21/text-rendering-methods-comparison-or-gdi-vs-gdi-revised/)

[Why does my text look different in GDI+ and in GDI?](https://vinsontech.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/why-does-my-text-look-different-in-gdi-and-in-gdi/)

[GDI vs. GDI+ Text Rendering Performance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2006/05/19/gdi-vs-gdi-text-rendering-performance/)

StackOverflow answers:

[Why is Graphics.MeasureString() returning a higher than expected number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203087/why-is-graphics-measurestring-returning-a-higher-than-expected-number)

[Modifying the kerning in System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235103/modifying-the-kerning-in-system-drawing-graphics-drawstring)

Application used to generate the ASCII-art text:
[ASCII Generator 2 on SourceForge (free software)](https://ascgendotnet.jmsoftware.co.uk/)