# How can I draw multi-colored text using graphics class on panel?

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics, drawstring, graphicspath

I want to draw the following text on panel:

[image: sample text]

It is a multi-colored text.

I found this [article](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/draw-text-in-random-colors-in-c/) about drawing multicolored text.

I replaced characters with words but it doesn't work.

[image: output-screenshot]

(I use FillPath/DrawPath to draw text)

**my code:**

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        const string txt = "C# Helper! Draw some text with each letter in a random color.";

        // Make the font.
        using (Font the_font = new Font("Times New Roman", 40,
            FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic))
        {
            // Make a StringFormat object to use for text layout.
            using (StringFormat string_format = new StringFormat())
            {
                // Center the text.
                string_format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                string_format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                string_format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;

                // Make CharacterRanges to indicate which
                // ranges we want to measure.

                MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(txt, @"[^\s]+");
                CharacterRange[] ranges = new CharacterRange[mc.Count];
                int g = 0;
                foreach (Match m in mc)
                {
                    ranges[g] = new CharacterRange(m.Index, m.Length);
                    g++;
                }
                string_format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges);

                // Measure the text to see where each character range goes.
                Region[] regions =
                    e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(
                        txt, the_font, this.ClientRectangle,
                        string_format);

                // Draw the characters one at a time.
                for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
                {
                    // See where this character would be drawn.
                    RectangleF rectf = regions[i].GetBounds(e.Graphics);
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
                        (int)rectf.X, (int)rectf.Y,
                        (int)rectf.Width, (int)rectf.Height);

                    // Make a brush with a random color.
                    using (Brush the_brush = new SolidBrush(RandomColor()))
                    {
                        // Draw the character.
                        string txts = txt.Substring(ranges[i].First, ranges[i].Length);
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(txts,
                            the_font, the_brush, rectf, string_format);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (in a way) a classic.
There is a discrepancy between the quite precise measure performed by [MeasureCharacterRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges?view=netframework-4.7.2) and the actual string drawing performed by `Graphics.DrawString`.

The `RectagleF` returned by `Region.GetBounds()` considers the measure of the Text as it is.
`Graphics.DrawString`, on the other hand, performs a sort of grid-fitting when calculating a Text disposition inside the given bounds.

I won't explain it here, it's quite a broad matter, but I've written something about it already:
[Drawing a Long String on to a Bitmap results in Drawing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943771/drawing-a-long-string-on-to-a-bitmap-results-in-drawing-issues?answertab=active#tab-top).
If you're interested, you can find some details on the `Graphics` object behaviour in this context.

The sum of it is, the Text is measured correctly, but the adjustments that `Graphics.DrawString` performs, cause the Text to not fit completely in the measured bounds: the drawn Text slightly *overflows*.

You could correct this *problem* using a couple of `StringFormat` flags:
Add [`[StringFormat].Trimming = StringTrimming.None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.trimming?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.StringFormat.Trimming);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2)

With this setting applied, you can immediately see what the problem is: the last char (or few chars) are wrapped to a new line, messing up the drawing.

To correct it, add [`StringFormatFlags.NoWrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformatflags?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to `StringFormatFlags.NoClip`
This will, apparently, solve the problem. Apparently because now the whole string is drawn on a single line.

I propose you another method, using [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.DrawText);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to render the strings.
Note that `TextRenderer` is actually the class used by the `WinForms` controls (well, not all of them) to render Text to the screen.

This is the result using the method that follows:

[image: MeasureCharacterRanges]

Sample code, using your original code with some modifications:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = sender as Control;
    const string txt = "C# Helper! Draw some text with each word in a random color.";

    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter |
                            TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.NoClipping;

    using (StringFormat format = new StringFormat())
    {
        format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(txt, @"[^\s]+");
        CharacterRange[] ranges = mc.Cast<Match>().Select(m => new CharacterRange(m.Index, m.Length)).ToArray();
        format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges);

        using (Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 40, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point))
        {
            Region[] regions = e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(txt, font, control.ClientRectangle, format);

            for (int i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
            {
                Rectangle WordBounds = Rectangle.Round(regions[i].GetBounds(e.Graphics));
                string word = txt.Substring(ranges[i].First, ranges[i].Length);

                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, word, font, WordBounds, RandomColor(), flags);
            }
        }
    }
}


private Random rand = new Random();
private Color[] colors =
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Green,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Lime,
    Color.Orange,
    Color.Fuchsia,
};

private Color RandomColor()
{
    return colors[rand.Next(0, colors.Length)];
}
```

Comment: Thankful.
In this case is there any way to add black outline to the text like sample text?

Comment: @Rasool g  With this method, it's hard. In `WinForms`, usually, `GraphicsPath` is the tool of choice. But the two are not compatible. Meaning, you can't draw a *countour*, with `GraphicsPath`, of the text you have drawn with `TextRenderer.DrawText` or `Graphics.DrawString`. Font, spacing, alignment won't match/overlap. You should draw all the parts with `GraphicsPath`. I've done something like this but for a vector design application. Too much code to post it here. Anyway, it could be interesting. Tomorrow I'll see if I can come up with something that can fit the SO *format*.