# How to compute the correct width of a digit in pixels?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+, measurestring

I have a custom control that may have user customizable Font in future (the zoom is already implemented). I must fill a rectangle under two digits that form a base-10 number. I have different colors for zero, one or both of the digits.

With the font {Name = `Microsoft Sans Serif` Size=`16`} and the following `Graphics.MeasureString` method calls:

```
g.MeasureString("00", Font);
g.MeasureString("0", Font);
```

I get:

- The size of "00" is {Width = `31.5486088` Height = `26.8124962`}
- The size of "0" is {Width = `19.3298588` Height = `26.8124962`}

The width of "0" is a lot bigger that half of the width of "00".

I know of the methods [Graphics.MeasureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring), it has many overloads, and I also know of the StringFormat class. How can I correctly compute the width of the '0' char?

Because the font will be user-customizable, I do not want to solve the problem using a monospace font.

If I use the following calls:

```
g.MeasureString("00", Font, 999, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
g.MeasureString("0", Font, 999, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

The width of "0" seems to be half of the width of "00", but the digits overlap when drawn with a smaller font size:

[image: screenshot]

**Update:** In the OnPaint method of an UserControl I have this code:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;

int[] indices = { 0, 1 };
CharacterRange[] charRanges = new CharacterRange[indices.Length];
for (int chx = 0; chx < indices.Length; ++chx)
{
    charRanges[chx] = new CharacterRange(indices[chx], 1);
}

StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericDefault);
sf.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(charRanges);

Region[] regions = e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges("01", Font, e.ClipRectangle, sf);

RectangleF[] r = new RectangleF[regions.Length];
int i = 0;
foreach (Region rr in regions)
{
    r[i] = rr.GetBounds(g);
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, r[i].X, r[i].Y, r[i].Width, r[i].Height);
    ++i;
}

g.DrawString("0", Font, Brushes.Black, r[0], sf);
g.DrawString("1", Font, Brushes.Black, r[1], sf);
```

The font is `{Name = "Microsoft Sans Serif" Size=25}`. When running the program, this is what is visible:

[image: screenshot 2]

I want to make the digits centered in the blue rectangles. The rectangles must be as big as possible in the UserControl but also leaving space for a percent of the Height of the UserControl. The Font should adapt to the rectangles.

Comment: Sorry if I badly understood, but I think that you should fill your rectangle and compute the size of the rectangle dynamically, at runtime, with the custom font.

Comment: The width of a character actually varies based on the string it's in, due to kerning. You'll probably need to move up to `MeasureCharacterRanges`.

Comment: Can you show how you're drawing the Rectagle and the Text? In not clear what is the procedure, here. Note that you can't measure a single letter; you should also consider the internal padding. As already noted, `MeasureCharacterRanges` could be the tool of choice, but it may not be necessary. What is that must fit? The text or the rectangle? The small graphics you posted doesn't clarify what is the expected result.

Comment: Btw, see these tests, with and without `MeasureCharacterRanges`: [How to highlight wrapped text in a control using the graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48257170/7444103) (see the warning). And the notes here: [How can I draw multi-colored text using graphics class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53028646/7444103).

Comment: @Jimi I added more details to the question.

Comment: As a detail. when choosing a Pen color, try to avoid reds. The `DrawRectagle` method, believe it or not, won't render it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small adjustments are required to make this work as intended:

1. **`TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit`** gives a better result when rendering the Text.
   It's more precise and works well with the grid-fitting nature of **`Graphics.DrawString`**.
   See the notes you can find in the answer linked below for more informations on this matter.
2. `StringFormat` alignment in both horizontal and vertical dimensions.
3. A modified method that allows to draw strings of any length.
   If the string is larger than the container, it will be wrapped, with the current settings.
4. Irrelevant: `Brush` and `Pen` are declared outside the Paint event, to allow their re-definition when required.

Different implementations of `MeasureCharacterRanges` here:
[How to highlight wrapped text in a control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48257170/7444103)

About `Graphics.DrawString` and `TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit`:
[Drawing a Long String on to a Bitmap results in Drawing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953353/7444103)

---

Font 48em:
[image: MeasureCharacterRanges 1]

Font 16em:
[image: MeasureCharacterRanges 2]

Font 9em:
[image: MeasureCharacterRanges 3]

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.LightGreen, 1);
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
string sourceDigits = "010011001";

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;

    CharacterRange[] charRanges = new CharacterRange[sourceDigits.Length];
    for (int chx = 0; chx < sourceDigits.Length; ++chx) {
        charRanges[chx] = new CharacterRange(chx, 1);
    }

    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(charRanges);

        Region[] regions = e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(sourceDigits, Font, e.ClipRectangle, sf);
        for (int i = 0; i < regions.Length; i++) {
            RectangleF rect = regions[i].GetBounds(e.Graphics);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(char.ToString(sourceDigits[i]), Font, brush, rect, sf);
        }
    }
}
```