# What enables WinForms Kerning

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

Under which conditions kerning is enabled on using DrawString?

I tried several Font and StringFormatFlags settings but was not successful. Any Hint would be appreciated.

[image] [image]

Please note the different rendering of "Te".

Comment: Do you want to enable it for a left (smaller font size) example? [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b087e606-81f2-44d2-ae13-e991c25d31c1/graphicsdrawstring-ignores-kerning-instructions) they suggest to use `DrawText`.

Comment: If I understood
: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-antialiasing-with-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, see [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning).

Comment: ok, I didn't know this. but are you using the same font?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis Anti-aliasing is not kerning. AA smoothes jagged edges. Kerning squeezes certain characters together.

Comment: Quote: _'WPF supports kerning, System.Drawing doesn't.   One workaround is to draw each individual character and do your own spacing.'_

Comment: DrawString() has many problems with output on low resolution devices (like monitors), it was Microsoft's first shot at resolution-independent rendering.  The basic reason why TextRenderer.DrawText() was added at v2.0.  WPF went through a similar ordeal, ideal vs display mode.

Comment: See the notes here: [Drawing a Long String on to a Bitmap results in Drawing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953353/7444103) -- [Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges) may be used to generate an *artificial* kerning.

Comment: @Charlieface, yep, I didn't know kerning but read about. Thanks