# Graphics.DrawString renders text with black outline on a transparent background

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm drawing a string on a Bitmap with transparent background using `Graphics.DrawString()` and I get text with a black contour, when the Font size is smaller than 23 millimeters (the Font is created with `GraphicsUnit.Millimeter`).

Code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(2000, 2000);
Color alpha = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
   for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
      bmp.SetPixel(x, y, alpha);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

Font labelFont = new Font("Cascadia Mono SemiBold", 23/*22*/, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
g.DrawString("Some text", labelFont, brush, 200, 200);
```

23 Millimeters-Units font:
[image: 23mm Font]

22 Millimeters-Units font:
[image: 23mm Font]

I tried to use `TextRenderer`, but this draws text without transparent background.

Comment: Side note: why are you calling SetPixel?  That's really slow.  Just draw a rectangle.

Comment: @LarsTech, after init bitmap has black background and FillRectangle сan't replace pixels to transparent. because image has 255 alpha

Comment: You are seeing the ClearType anti-aliasing pixels, trying to blend the letter shape to black.  DrawString() is not capable of handling alpha.  You'll either need a well-defined background color or give up on anti-aliasing with TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel/GridFit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code presented here has multiple problems:

- The initial loop is counter-productive for multiple reasons:

  - Tries to fill a Bitmap with a transparent color, but this is already the non-color associated with a newly created Bitmap (`Color.FromArb(0, 0, 0, 0)`)
  - Uses the `SetPixel()` method, the slowest possible tool for the task

    - If needed, a Bitmap can be filled with a Color using the [Graphics.Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.clear) method, which calls a native GDI+ function to perform the task
- Setting an [InterpolationMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode) in this context is not useful, this property selects the algorithm used to **scale or rotate images**
- The [SmoothingMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.smoothingmode) property selects the algorithm used to anti-aliasing **lines, curves and the edges of filled areas**. It doesn't apply to the rendering of Fonts, so has no effect on the drawn text. It applies to text rendered with a GraphicsPath, since the text is converted to curves
- None of the disposable objects (**Graphics**, **Font**, **Brush**) is either disposed explicitly or declared with `using` statements (which is pretty bad). It's not clear when the Bitmap is disposed, but could be the duty of the code that uses it

To specify the rendering mode of Fonts, the [TextRenderingHint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint) property is used instead. Since it's not specified, the System default smoothing of Font is used, usually ClearType.

About this rendering form, see the notes in:
[Drawing a Long String on to a Bitmap results in Drawing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953353/7444103)

ClearType uses intra-pixel smoothing, designed initially for LCD screens, to blend text with a background; it's especially effective with small Fonts sizes. It doesn't support alpha colors (not in this context, at least).
The device context in which the text is rendered, a GDI+ [MemoryBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.memorybmp), doesn't use or *understand* this type of hinting (smoothing), so the pixels that fail to render are filled with an empty color, which notoriously appears as black
A black-ish *contour* might manifests with different Font sizes (not just the measures reported in the question), when the ClearType hinting fill is less than one pixel

To fix the rendering, remove the clutter, specify a suitable `TextRenderingHint` mode and declare correctly all disposable objects.
I'm not including the Bitmap, because I don't know how it's used. It must be disposed at some point, of course (very important, it allocates unmanaged resources, the Garbage Collector cannot help you)

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(2000, 2000);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
using (var font = new Font("Cascadia Mono SemiBold", 22, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter))
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White)) {
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
    g.DrawString("Some text", font, brush, 200, 200);
}
```

`TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit` is appropriate here (see also the linked notes), the characters are drawn using their anti-aliased glyph bitmap and hinting (smoothing)
`TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias` can also be used in this context (and *costs* slightly less)

`CompositingQuality.HighQuality` is not actually used here, there isn't really any composition, since no image is rendered against a background (which may require gamma correction), but also has no *cost*. You can keep it, in case you decide to draw a bitmap onto the current, at some point; or simply remove it.

---

About *TextRenderer draws text without transparent background*

This is not correct. [TextRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer) (**GDI**) can of course render text with a transparent background, it just doesn't support an alpha color (in this context)
As mentioned, we're working with an in-memory **GDI+** Device Context
But, if you draw the same text in a different Device Context, e.g., the surface of a Control, then things change.
Also note that TextRenderer cannot be used to render text when printing (for the same reasons previously described).

Test this code, subscribing to the Paint event of a PictureBox, also adding a background Image (without a background image the result doesn't change, it's just more visible)

`Graphics.DrawString()` is used to render text with a semi-transparent (ARGB) Color

```
TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.Top;

private void someControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var font = new Font("Segoe UI", 22, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter))
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White)) {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Some text", font, 
            new Rectangle(new Point(0, 10), pictureBox1.ClientSize), Color.White, Color.Transparent, flags);

        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Some text", font, brush, 0, 130);
    }

    using (Font font1 = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.0f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter))
    using (Font font2 = new Font("Segoe UI", 5.5f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter))
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Black))) {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("← TextRenderer", font1, brush, 610, 70);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("ForeColor: White, BackColor: Transparent", font2, brush, 610, 110);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("← GDI+ Graphics", font1, brush, 610, 190);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("ForeColor: White, Hinting: AntiAliasGridFit", font2, brush, 610, 230);
    }
}
```

Resulting in (enlarge it):

[image: TextRenderer.DrawText vs. Graphics.DrawString()]