# Drawing monospaced font in a picture box

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm trying to display text in a picture box using monospaced font, however the displayed characters don't exactly have fixed width (most are 7 pixels wide but some are 8). In the image below, the text on top is a label created on the main form, with font set as follows:

```
Font lucida9 = new Font("Lucida Console", 9F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))); 
testLabel.Font = lucida9;
```

The text on bottom is displayed in the picture box Paint event using the same font:

```
public void textPicBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(testLabel.Text, testLabel.Font, Brushes.Black, new Point(0, 0)); 
}
```

Both the label and the picture box were created using the designer.
I tried playing with graphics properties (TextRenderingHint, PixelOffsetMode, etc.), using Pixel as graphics unit when creating the font, using an image in the picture box instead of drawing directly on it, but to no avail.

Cheers

[image: Output image]

Comment: Text is not renderer with `Graphics.DrawString()`, but with `TextRenderer.DrawText()` -- `Graphics.DrawString()` has a grid fitting feature. Read the notes here: [Drawing a Long String on to a Bitmap results in Drawing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953353/7444103), if you're interested